# How to use git command line via SourceTree on Windows

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am currently using SourceTree on Windows 7. If I run into any problems with my git repository the solutions online always rely on the command line. Is there anyway to enter these commands in SourceTree?

Answer (score 19):

From the `Actions` menu select `Open In terminal`. You will be presented with a poor shell in which you can use git commands

Comment: @PascalKlein Not as it may seem. I remember I spend myself a lot of time trying to do the same stuff you wanted to do. I just skipped past that option many times because I thought it would open just a normal Windows `cmd` terminal

Comment: Don't know when, but I need to do `eval $(/usr/bin/ssh-pageant.exe -qra /tmp/.ssh-pageant-auth)` to get ssh-agent working inside this shell. Just a tip if anyone else is having authentication problems.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to open that poor shell is just by clicking on Terminal icon in the main window
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Sourcetree's embedded git from the terminal. Add this to your powershell profile:

```
Add-PathVariable "${env:UserProfile}\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin"
```

Comment: Good answer but it will work only for people who use PowerShell community extensions. For clean PowerShell the following line in profile will work as well:
`${env:PATH} += "${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin"`